# YQL, returning only 100 values. Can I get more?

Tags: yql

I'm using YQL with JSON in order to retrieve a Twitter search.  It only returns 100 values. Any chance to get more than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look good, friend: "The maximum number of results that can be returned by a YQL query on this table is 100, which is defined by the attribute max."

From: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-tutorials.html

Comment: I see I can modify it using xml, however I don't see any for json :(! thanks anyway fella!

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of items returned by a `SELECT` statement with YQL is 5,000. If the table in query does not give enough results by default (assuming there are more available), you can ask for more results by using a **remote limit**.

```
select * from twitter.search(250) where q="lol"
```

For more details, see [Paging and Table Limits](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html) in the YQL Guide.

---

Be aware that many data providers will rate limit queries against their services, Twitter certainly does.